# Can I use a Chi-Square test to compare a cumulative distribution and quantitative data?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, computational-statistics

I am trying to compare the goodness of fits of an exponential and a log-normal distributions to some empirical data. Is it possible to use a chi-square test to do so, even though the data is quantitative?

In the section 2 of this paper (http://physics.umd.edu/~yakovenk/papers/PhysicaA-370-54-2006.pdf) the author use the chi-square test for that. But no matter where I look, the chi-square is always used for categorical data.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: You bin the data.  The details matter, though: if you don't carry this out exactly the right way, you will get the wrong results.  In an answer to a different question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148/919, I explain the details and provide worked examples.

Comment: Thank you @whuber, I understand. It's a shame I can't rank this.